# Не могу ни как подключить приложение андройд к гугл таблицам, нужна только запись без редактирования и просмотра, и без обратной отправки

Tags: java, android, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Писал приложение на Андройд студио, на языке Java. Подключал через Apps Scripts, то есть создавая JS скрипт. Прилагаю скрипт из Андройд студио:

```
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class TestGS2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etName, etPhone, etAddress;
    ImageButton btnInsert;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_gs2);

    etName = findViewById(R.id.et_name_id);
    etPhone = findViewById(R.id.et_phone_id);
    etAddress = findViewById(R.id.et_address_id);
    btnInsert = findViewById(R.id.btn_insert_id);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TestGS2.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addStudentData();
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    });
    }

    public void addStudentData() {
    String sName = etName.getText().toString();
    String sPhone = etPhone.getText().toString();
    String sAddress = etAddress.getText().toString();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
```

"https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwKsMEFv2L3sSYbtHP7IRaX6z7D2ODlg9f1yaBg_8ACu6UveilbIq5x7q
CxFzMP1Ehn/exec", new Response.Listener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SuccessActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    progressDialog.hide();
    }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("action", "addStudent");
            params.put("vName", sName);
            params.put("vPhone", sPhone);
            params.put("vAdres", sAddress);

            return params;
        }
    };
    int socketTimeout = 50000;
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, 0, 
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    }
```

Также вот зависимости из gradle:

```
   dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
   implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
   implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
   exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
   }
   implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev508-1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
   }
   }
    
   Разрешения из манифеста:

    
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

   <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

плюс в gradle все прописал:

```
     buildscript {
     repositories {
               google()
               mavenCentral()
     }

     dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

     }
     }

     allprojects {

     repositories {
     google()
     mavenCentral()
     }
     }

     task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
     }
```

И вот сам скрипт где я получаю данные из приложения, это уже в сервисе Apps Script:

```
     function doPost(e){
     var ss = 
     SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aJ3eRZJBjpLzwM5FtURgG- 
     Jm6keM8GkfI89JDqh10MA/edit#gid=0");
                              
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('StudentData');
     var action = e.parameter.action;

     if(action == 'addStudent'){
     var name = e.parameter.vName;
     var phone = e.parameter.vPhone;
     var address = e.parameter.vAddress  
     sheet.appendRow([name,phone,address]);
     return 
     ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
     }
     }
```

В итоге в приложении крутится загрузка, ошибку не дает, но и больше ничего не происходит.
А в сервисе когда нажимаешь на проверку выдает ошибку :

```
     Ошибка 
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameter' of undefined
     doPost @ Код.gs:5
```

типа параметр не определен, и в таблицу ничего не понятное дело не записывается.
Может кто сталкивался, помогите уже всю голову сломал (((

Comment: Здрравствуйте не могли бы вы пожалуйста там где onErrorResponse написать: Log.println(Log.ERROR, "Error from volley", error.toString()) . Хочу посмотреть что в логах выводится. Также если это открывать через обычную браузерную страницу то эта ошибка всегда будет появляться). Отправьте то что в логах сюда

Comment: Я был скопировал ваш код и ошибка скорее всего была в скрипте Apps Script.Попробуйте там где переменная sheet заменить на это:
var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Data');

У вас было неправильно указано обращение к столбцу. Также рекомендую добавить проверку в коде примерно такую:

<code>
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.equals("Success")) {
                    //do something
                } else {
                    //show error
                }
            }
</code> 

Там где return соедените со строкой ниже

Comment: Принял, спасибо попробую )